# @typescript-eslint/member-ordering not working

Tags: json, typescript, eslint, rules

I'm trying to have a strict ordering in typescript classes, forcing a precise order for groups and especially I'd like to force alphabetic order.

I'm following this doc to achieve what I need: https://typescript-eslint-armano.netlify.app/rules/member-ordering/#sorting-alphabetically-within-member-groups

This is the member-ordering config extracted by my .eslintrc config

```json
"@typescript-eslint/member-ordering": [
      "error",
      {
          "default": {
            "memberTypes": [
              "public-static-field",
              "protected-static-field",
              "private-static-field",
              "public-instance-field",
              "public-decorated-field",
              "public-abstract-field",
              "protected-instance-field",
              "protected-decorated-field",
              "protected-abstract-field",
              "private-instance-field",
              "private-decorated-field",
              "private-abstract-field",
              "static-field",
              "public-field",
              "instance-field",
              "protected-field",
              "private-field",
              "abstract-field",
              "constructor",
              "public-static-method",
              "protected-static-method",
              "private-static-method",
              "public-method",
              "protected-method",
              "private-method"
            ],
            "order": "alphabetically"
          }
      }
    ],
```

This doesn't produce any errors in my class, whereas I would expect 2 errors: wrong member ordering (private should go after public) and wrong alphabetic order.

[image: no errors]

Eslint is running fine, since I'm getting other errors, such as naming-convention and others

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that separating `memberTypes` and `ordering` in two categories, works.
It appeared to me that the docs put the two props together, but maybe it's a bug.

[image: new config]

And in my editor:

[image: working as expected now]

Answer (score -3):

Try this list as per https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/member-ordering.md#default-configuration:

```
// Index signature
"signature",
"call-signature",

// Fields
"public-static-field",
"protected-static-field",
"private-static-field",
"#private-static-field",

"public-decorated-field",
"protected-decorated-field",
"private-decorated-field",

"public-instance-field",
"protected-instance-field",
"private-instance-field",
"#private-instance-field",

"public-abstract-field",
"protected-abstract-field",

"public-field",
"protected-field",
"private-field",
"#private-field",

"static-field",
"instance-field",
"abstract-field",

"decorated-field",

"field",

// Static initialization
"static-initialization",

// Constructors
"public-constructor",
"protected-constructor",
"private-constructor",

"constructor",

// Getters
"public-static-get",
"protected-static-get",
"private-static-get",
"#private-static-get",

"public-decorated-get",
"protected-decorated-get",
"private-decorated-get",

"public-instance-get",
"protected-instance-get",
"private-instance-get",
"#private-instance-get",

"public-abstract-get",
"protected-abstract-get",

"public-get",
"protected-get",
"private-get",
"#private-get",

"static-get",
"instance-get",
"abstract-get",

"decorated-get",

"get",

// Setters
"public-static-set",
"protected-static-set",
"private-static-set",
"#private-static-set",

"public-decorated-set",
"protected-decorated-set",
"private-decorated-set",

"public-instance-set",
"protected-instance-set",
"private-instance-set",
"#private-instance-set",

"public-abstract-set",
"protected-abstract-set",

"public-set",
"protected-set",
"private-set",
"#private-set",

"static-set",
"instance-set",
"abstract-set",

"decorated-set",

"set",

// Methods
"public-static-method",
"protected-static-method",
"private-static-method",
"#private-static-method",

"public-decorated-method",
"protected-decorated-method",
"private-decorated-method",

"public-instance-method",
"protected-instance-method",
"private-instance-method",
"#private-instance-method",

"public-abstract-method",
"protected-abstract-method",

"public-method",
"protected-method",
"private-method",
"#private-method",

"static-method",
"instance-method",
"abstract-method",

"decorated-method",

"method"
```

Comment: That wouldn't do alphabetic order grouped like I needed. Also that's where I started.

Comment: The OP also wrote in the question that he was following the docs.